# Can I redirect the http request towards an old folder to the homepage using .htaccess file?

Tags: redirect, htaccess, server, apache

I am in the following situation: I had an old blog that was made using Joomla (this blog was indexed well enough by search engines). Due to some problems I deleted it and moved the site over to WordPress/

Now I have many visits (from Google) that lead to specific pages of the old site (pages that don't exist in the new version).

For example I have visits to URLs as `/scorejava/index.php/corso-spring-mvc/1-test` that doesn't exist on my new site.

I would know if using the .htaccess file (or other system) I can redirect the HTTP Request directed to some subfolder (that don't exist in the new version) to the homepage of my new site .

For example I have the request towards the empty URL: `/scorejava/index.php/corso-spring-mvc/1-test` and I would create a regular expression that say something like: all the request toward the subfolder `/corso-spring-mvc` (and all it's content file and subfolder) have to be redirected to `www.scorejava.com`

Is it possible?

Comment: Pure .htaccess rewrite questions are not really WordPress specific. On Stack Overflow they aren’t welcome anymore too, so I answered here – and closed it.

Answer (score 1):

That should be easy:

```
RedirectMatch Permanent corso-spring-mvc/ /
```